# form and .append issue

Tags: jquery, forms, append

Having difficulties with this form.

I am using #message div tag in html.

I can get first and last name to appear, but if I forget to enter a name I can't get "Please enter your first and last name to appear". I have tried various ways with no luck. Anyone know what I am missing?

```
var getName = function()
{ 
var fullName;
if(document.getElementById("FirstName").value == "" &&    document.getElementById("LastName").value == "")
{
    //fullName = "Please enter your first and last name";
     $("#message").empty().append(fullName = "Please enter your first and last    name");
}
else
{

    $("#message").empty().append (fullName  =  document.getElementById("FirstName").value + " " + document.getElementById("LastName").value); 
}
return  $("#message").empty().append(fullName);
}
  var displayName = function()
  {

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#message").empty().append(Hello);
});
  }
```

here is the html

```
<div id="message"></div>

<form name="form" id="form" method="post" action="">  

<p class="FirstName">  
    <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  </p>
    <p>
    <input name="FirstName" type="text" id="FirstName" />  

</p>  

<p class="LastName">  
    <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label></p>
    <p>
    <input name="LastName" type="text" id="LastName" />  

</p>


<p class="submit">  
    <input name="submitButton" type="button" id="submitButton" value="Get Name" onClick="getName()" />
</p>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`fullName = ...` is an assignment, it returns `undefined`, so you are appending an `undefined` value,  remove the `fullName =`. Also you should use quotes for strings, change `Hello` to `"Hello"` and as a suggestion do not mix Vanilla JavaScript with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#message").text('Hello *');

   $('form').on('submit', function(event){
      var first = $('#FirstName').val(),
          last = $('#LastName').val();
      if (first === '' || last === '') {
         event.preventDefault();
         $("#message").html("Please enter your bloody first and last name");
      }
   });
});
```

Using `onClick` is not a good practice, specially when you are using jQuery, you can listen to `submit` event using jQuery `on` method, also note that `append` returns a jQuery object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, so `return $("#message").empty().append(fullName); === return true;`.